# Make binary executable available for all user

Tags: linux, software-installation, executable

How to make a binary file available for all linux(Ubuntu) user.
eg:
When we install the golang using  `apt install golang-go` the go executable is available for all user.

Where will they add the configuration for that.

I checked it in global level  */etc/environment, /etc/profile, /etc/init.d/*  i couldn't find any reference there !

```
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 16.04.4 LTS
Release:        16.04
Codename:       xenial
```

Its not even in ~/.bashrc or ~/.profile; even-though these files are user specific.

Since the **apt install gives the old version of go**; i need to manually **install the latest version of go and make it available for all the user**.

Comment: What version of Ubuntu are you running?

Comment: @Kusalananda Ubuntu, xenial

Comment: *"the configuration for that"* is a user's `PATH`; typically, software that is compiled from source and intended to be available to all users would install its executable files in `/usr/local/bin`

Comment: Have you checked the `xenial-backports` repositories for a newer version?

Comment: @steeldriver So if i want to manually install a new binary, let say go itself. The directory will be go/{api, blog, doc, lib, pkg, test..........., bin}. But the actual executable is  go/bin/go, so should i create a file in /usr/local/bin as go_symlink and link it to $HOME/go/bin/go file !

Comment: @ivanivan Package: golang-1.10, Version: 1.10-1ubuntu1~16.04.1 available in http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ubuntu/dists/xenial-backports/universe/binary-amd64/

Comment: Well, `golang` is kind of a special case: I *think* there are environment variables such as `GOROOT_FINAL` that may be used during the build to do what you want, but I have no experience with that. The main point is that **outside of the OS's own package management system** (i.e. dpkg/apt in the case of Ubuntu) there is no global setting that controls where software gets installed - that's up to the build configuration of the particular software.

Answer (score 7):

When [*executing*](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man3/exec.3.html) a command without specifying a path, the system searches for the executable in locations specified in `PATH` environmental variable. Paths in `PATH`-variable are searched in order and first found executable is used.

[`/usr/local/bin`](http://refspecs.linuxfoundation.org/FHS_3.0/fhs/ch04s09.html) is a reasonable place to install your own executables as it is possibly already included in the distribution provided default `PATH` and it should not conflict with system's package manager. If the directory structure of your program makes placing files in `/usr/local/` inconvinient, another reasonable location to place the files is in [`/opt`](http://refspecs.linuxfoundation.org/FHS_3.0/fhs/ch03s13.html) under its own subdirectory (and additionally creating symbolic links/launch scripts in `/usr/local/bin`).